# Android make MapView loading faster

Tags: android, dictionary, preload

hi my app is sometimes used in rural areas where there is no 3g network so the first time the mapview loads it is really slow.

I would like to be able to to preload some tiles in the background ( in a service or in the main activity (home activity)) in order to speed up this download.

I have seen there is a method  mapView.preLoad() but it only works with a mapView object. How could I do the same thing from a service? I thought to do like that:

```
MapView mv=new MapView(this, getResources().getString(R.string.MAP_API_KEY));

mv.preLoad();
```

problem is if the context is not a MapActivity this will throw an exception.

Here would be the flow of the app:

user starts app

main activity gets location data and stats downloading data for the map

user opens map activity

Map activity laods faster because it's downloaded data is already in the cache

any ideas of what I can do? thks in advance for advice

Comment: which one? I have tried something similar with FreeMap but it seemed slower... could you give more details about your suggestion?

Comment: I don't use anyone else so wont be able to give good advice, but search stack overflow there is some post about it :)

Comment: Try OpenStreetMap. The Osmdroid is an (almost) complete clone of Google's MapView so switching should be easy. And I think it supports offline tiles. http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Answer (score 4):

I was using android `Mapview` inside a fragment but when i load the map with coordinates it did not loaded at all. So i found a solution for this.

firt initialize the map in onCreate method.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null);
map = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
map.onCreate(this.savedInstance);
```

then set the map view like this.

```
private void setUpMap() {
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Place Lable").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_drawable)));


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15));


    map.onResume();
}
```

this key point in this code is to call `map.onResume();` after setting the `Map`

Comment: Not sure how this works for you because `MapView.onCreate(Bundle)` is where `MapView` gets slow...also, you are suggesting to call `onResume` right after `onCreate` which is wrong